# How to use __doPostBack() function in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, onclick, postback, dopostback

I am trying to trigger button event from the JS code. But `doPostBack` in JS function `reg()` is not directing to the c# code. Please tell me what's wrong. Here is my code:

```
<script>
    function reg() {
        var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
        var id = document.getElementById('cnic').value;
        var age = document.getElementById('age').value;
        var ph = document.getElementById('phone').value;
        var pas = document.getElementById('pass').value;
        if (id == '' || pas == '' || age == '' || ph == '' || pas == '')
            window.alert("Write all fields");
        else {
            __doPostBack('<%= Button1.UniqueID%>','')
        }
    }
</script>
<div >
       <asp:Button id="Button1" OnClientClick="reg()"  runat="server" Text="Submit"/>
    </div>
```

Here is the server side c# function associated with the button:

```
protected void Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button clickedButton = (Button)sender;
    clickedButton.Text = "...button clicked...";
}
```

Note: In else block, I want `reg()` function to redirect to the `Btn_Click` function.

Comment: It looks like you don't have your server side `Btn_Click` event attached to your `asp:Button id="Button1"`. Are you attaching it elsewhere?

Comment: This question is duplicate  of [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53523797/dopostback-function-isnt-working-asp-net)